# Как конвертировать сложный json ( с типами timestamp) объект в Java объект, используя gson?

Tags: java, json, gson, timestamp

```
{
   "errorMsg":"Предупреждение -251",
   "timeStamp":1535440882574,
   "status":1,
   "voId":"0000021",
   "IDN":"201050000006010003ah05a0000",
   "param":{  
      "cur2":null,
      "partner":"вфц",
      "number":"435",
      "date":1528873200221,
      "sum1":11016.0,
      "sum2":null,
      "cur1":"840"
   }
}
```

Вот этот объект я не могу парсить уже 2 дня?

Comment: Данный процесс называется десириализацией. Для этого я обычно использую библиотеку Jackson (более гибкая в настройке). Для GSON пробуйте что-то типа new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(DateFormat.LONG).create();

Comment: Я попробовал, именно  1535440882574-это не парсируется, я нашел другие примеры но  у них число не 13-разрядные а 10-разрядные. Не нашёл ни одного примера с 13-разрядным. С 10-разрядным числом проблеме не будет, это тип long. А   тип 1535440882574 не long, не String.

Comment: Если числовое представление времени то это обычно милисекунды. Кто вам сказал что 1535440882574 не лонг?

Comment: 1535440882574-Java не понимает что это лонг. 1535440882574L-если так то понятно, проблема в том что этого число я не могу парсит  как long

Comment: При чем здесь литералы мы говорим о числовом значении. См. логику своего 'парсинга'.

Comment: литералы здесь не в чем. КАК МОЖНО КОНВЕРТИРОВАТЬ JSON (на верху) В JAVA ОБЪЕКТ?

Comment: смотреть ответ ниже

Comment: парсить и конвертировать - это разные вещи, в какой класс вы хотите распарсить json?

Answer (score 0):

Используя GSON что-то типа:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder(); 
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() { 
   public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
      return new Date(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsLong()); 
   } 
});
Gson gson = builder.create();
//...
```

Comment: это уже я попробовал не работает?